# How does blockchain.info get miner revenue?

Tags: blockchain.info

In the [stats page](https://blockchain.info/stats) of blockchain.info, I see the revenue of miners is $1,680,297.91. As I understand, its the total money that people have spent on buying their miners. But, i doubt that since its a bit too small compared to the total revenue of Bitcoin market. So I have some questions as following

1. What is the meaning of that number?
2. How does blockchain.info compute it? Will it be updated frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number means something else then you expect. It is the value of the reward for the miners, so exactly the revenue.

I will show you how this number is calculated:

There are (currently, may differ in the future) 144 blocks mined. That means that there are 144*25 = 3600 bitcoins awarded to miners. The value of 1 bitcoin is  $465.07 USD according to the statistic page. The 3600 bitcoins have a total value of $1,674,252 USD. Add a little of the transaction fees (13.41473297 BTC, which is 0.37% according to the statistics page) and this will results in the 1.68 million USD revenue.

Blockchain can simply calculate all these things from the different blocks, because everything is also on the site.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a bunch. Do you know if we can estimate the total money that people have spent on miners?

Comment: That's a whole new question, but I think you can only guess it. I don't think companies who sell miners are happy to give away selling information. And then there is the difficulty by determining which GPU's (and CPU's a few years ago) were bought for mining purposes.

Comment: It's the cost of electricity, premises and equipment investments. I guess most of big mining operations keep this information secret. But you can get some proportions of the operations by reading this page: http://www.bitfury.org/